# WearableListView first Item selected by Default

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, wear-os

I would make sure that my application for devices Android Wear the first element of my WearableListView is selected by default when i start the application. I tried everything but without success and the many guides that I find on the web dealing with this subject for a normal ListView NOT for devices WearableListView primed for Android Wear, thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you meant by selected by default ?why do you want to select the first item selected ? And show us some code what you"ve done.

Comment: So.. Tizen is not Android.. Android Wear has nothing to do with Tizen Wearable SDK, Do you want to know somthing about Tizen?